# Is it slow to read data from a json file with rootBundle.loadString?

Tags: json, flutter, asynchronous, dart

I was just wondering if it is relatively slow to read data from an asset json file using `rootBundle.loadString`.

I know this is an async process and I should await it, so does that mean that I shouldn't do that too often or maybe should I show a loading indicator while reading the file? or is it not that slow?

Comment: You need to use a FutureBuilder.

Comment: what if I'm loading json string to fill a dropdownmenu in a screen with other input fields? I'm thinking I can just load the strings in initState() for example? is that a bad practice?

Comment: it's an async operation, you want to build UI out of Future so FutureBuilder fits perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

loadString uses `compute` (i.e. run an isolate) for files > 10Kb (see to the function implementation for latest details). I discovered that isolates work (or start, does not matter) slow on certain Android devices (Samsung J5 2017, for instance). Not sure why - is it slow device or some multithread invocation issues for this architecture. So you may just use 'rootBundle.load()' directly, like:

```
Future<String> loadString(String key) async {
    final ByteData data = await rootBundle.load(key);
    return utf8.decode(data.buffer.asUint8List());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`loadString` returns a Future, So you can use a [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) to build dropdown out of future data.

```dart
// other code

FutureBuilder(
    future: rootBundle.loadString('path-to-file.json'),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            // return a widget using snapshot's data.
        }
        // handle other connectionStats.
    },
),

// other code
```